# How to make a asynchronous app with Node, Express

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

I'm working on an app that i being built using Node and Express. All is fine, however the app is currently not asynchronous and I'd like it to be, so I'm currently investigating what would be the best way to do it.

As far as I can tell, socket.io seems to be the preferred choice to go with Node.

My question is, is socket.io's methodology the best way to move data between the server and client or is there a better, more robust way to do it? Maybe something accomplished with Node only?

PS: I think socket.io sounds really nice. Its just that I'm new to Node and though there would be a simpler way to move data back and forth.

Many thanks

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've seen the term "realtime" used before and was frown upon. The commenter implied that technically there is no "realtime" application, hence me choosing asynchronous, however realtime does describe what I'm after: An app that will be all ajax-like. For instance, in my app, when I need to edit a saved document (mongodb records are called documents), I need to redirect the page passing the document id as argument. I don't want that. I want all through ajax. I can achieve this with jQuery, however behind the scenes the server will still be moving through urls (I'll need to create loads of `app.get('product/:id/edit', ...), app.post('/product/:id/edit'. ...`  and then use $.ajax to get and post stuff ) so I was wondering what's the best way to achieve this.

PS: I might be looking at this completely wrong. Like I said, I'm new to Node and for app development for that matter.

**EDIT2:** An example: Let's say I have a page with a table in it where I list all products. Each product will have a EDIT/DELETE button. At the moment, when I click edit, I'm redirected to another page where I can edit the product and save it, then I'm redirected to the product listing. I'd prefer to load the product into a modal window, make whatever edits I need, then update the product/listing without leaving the page.

Using $.ajax I can use the product ID, enquiry the db for that particular product, populate the field in the modal with the product details and display to the user. Then allow the user to make the changes and update the products, however the part in which I need to enquiry the db in order to populate the modal is muddy because the id needs to be passed through the url...

I don't know how to pass the id to the application unless is through `app.get('/product/:id/edit', ...)` then `app.post('/product/:id/edit')`.

Comment: Yup! socket.io is the best choice here. socket.io library in the backend will manage everything, you have to just add your code assuming that the underlying platforms supports sockets and even if it doesn't support socket.io will manage it for you(using the means supported by the platform) and hence your application then can be deployed everywhere..

Comment: what do you mean its not asynchronous? the whole point for node as an architecture is that its asynchronous...

Comment: You might need to clarify what you want to achieve. There isn't really such a thing as making an app asynchronous. As for what's the best way to move data between the server and the client it also depends on what you're trying to do. Websockets are only meaningful when you want the server to initiate the transferal of data.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is *realtime*, not *asynchronous*.